# No Refresh() method for ListView in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition. I get an error when I try to use the refresh() method for ListView control in my web form. It says there is no such thing for ListView control whereas the documentation on msdn says it should have one.

Right now, I am refreshing the content of the control by changing the SELECT command of the Sql Data Source that the control is bound to. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView for WinForms has a Refresh Method however ASP.Net does not afaik.  I think a solution to your problem can be found here [How do I refresh an ASP.NET ListView using jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322318/how-do-i-refresh-an-asp-net-listview-using-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: You are correct, there is no `Refresh` method on the web control.  Supporting documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx